# Angular Library - Inherit from parent app

Tags: angular

Essentially I've created a library to help make my angular code reusable for future apps. The library will get imported and sit in the node_modules directory.

A component in this library needs to make reference to the **route.config.js** file from the Parent App.

I am struggling to figure out how I would be able to either inherit this file from the parent app or make reference to it in the imported library module.

It's also worth noting that I am using Angular4 with AOT compilation so unable to us ab absolute path to point to the file, like so:

```
import {routing} from '../../../../../app/route.config';
```

The route.config.ts file/path won't also exist during development of the Library.

Any ideas would be massively appreciated.

**Soft Solution:**

For this particular example, the route config details are stored in an Array. e.g.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [canActivateRoute],
    data: { }
  },
```

With this, I was able to pass the array though an **@Input** on the component where it was needed.

Child Component in Library:

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() routing: any;
```

.html file in Parent:

```
 <navigation [ngClass]="{ 'hidden': !_isLoggedIn }" routes="routing">
```

I've marked this as a soft solution as ideally I would need to reference a whole component, but for now this does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should import your exported module or component from the shared library.

Let assume that your shared library have exported **USERSharedModule**

**SharedModule**

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [USERSharedModule]
})
```

you should import USERSharedModule module in your code.

In your App

**app.module.ts**

```
import { USERSharedModule} from '@route/Shared';
```

Comment: Thanks. However I probably didn't make it very clear that the imported module would then need to be edited for each App, but also made global back to the Library. 

It's a tough one to get your head around.